# Country fixed effects in probit regression in R

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I have a panel data set which contains year, ccode (countrycode), iso, loans, crisisJST (whether the year was a systemic crisis year or not). I want to do a probit regression with the function 'probitmfx' and induce 'ccode' as fixed effects. I wanted to use 'factor(ccode)' to include dummy variables but it shows me the following error:

```
probitmfx(crisisJST ~ laons + factor(ccode), clustervar1 = "iso", data = data_post) 
Error in factor(ccode) : Object 'ccode' not found
```

Is there another option to include fixed effects?

Comment: If you have checked that your data genuinely contains a column called `ccode` with no capitals or spaces, perhaps try converting it to a factor before passing it in a formula. `data_post$ccode <- factor(data_post$ccode)` then running the model as `probitmfx(crisisJST ~ laons + ccode, clustervar1 = "iso", data = data_post)` . Also, you say one of your columns is called "loans" but you have "laons" in your formula.

Comment: 0

I tried this and I get values I expect but if I want to get an output of it with 'export_summs' I get an output including all 17 dummy variables which I can't unfortunately leave out.